# How to transform string to object id in nodejs

Tags: express, mongoose

** Help me to solve this error **

```
try {
    return res.status(200).json({
      error: false,
     Posts: await Post.find({ group: groupId }).populate('group', 'name'),
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: 'Cannot fetch post' });
  }
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: I am not getting value from database but in terminal  its showing like this App listen to port: 3000
Mongodb running
GET /api/groups/5cf63667c3aa330eb53b4704/posts 200 5490.717 ms - 28

Comment: and in postman its showing posts value null like this : {
    "error": false,
    "posts": [ ]
}

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
try {

Post.find({ group: groupId }).populate('group', 'name').exec((err,posts)=>{
    if(err){
       return res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    } 

    if(posts){
        return res.status(200).json({
        error: false,
        Posts: posts
       });
     }else{
       return res.status(400).json({ error: true, message: 'Cannot fetch post' });
     }
});

  } catch (e) {
   return res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: 'Internal Server Error' });
 }
```

Comment: i think your mongoose connection not working , show your Post Model

Comment: import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const GroupSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    minLength: [5, 'Name must be 5 characters long'],
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: [10, 'Description must be 10 characters long'],
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
  },
  posts: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post',
  }],
}, { timestamps: true });

Comment: GroupSchema.statics.addPost = async function (id, args) {
  const Post = mongoose.model('Post');
  // We add the group id to the post group element
  // Finally this is the author of the post
  const post = await new Post({ ...args, group: id });
  // We found the group with the id provide in the url
  // And we push the post id in the posts element
  const group = await this.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $push: { posts: post.id } });
  return {
    post: await post.save(),
    group,
  }; };
export default mongoose.model('Group', GroupSchema);